# Link rospack to newer version of boost

Tags: ros, boost, build-from-source, rospack

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I was follwing the ROS tutorials where I had to create the beginner tutorial package. I used the following command

```
catkin_create_pkg beginner_tutorials std_msgs rospy roscpp
```

After that when I tried out the follwing *rospack* command I got an error

```
 rospack depends1 beginner_tutorials
```

The error is

```
rospack: error while loading shared libraries : libboost_filesystem.so.1.63.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Upon investigating, I realized that I have the boost version 1.65.1

How can I ask the ROS to look for the newer version of Boost?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/271713/link-rospack-to-newer-version-of-boost/) by [kennethjp](https://answers.ros.org/users/32048/kennethjp/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2017-09-28

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-09-28**:
Can you tell us how you installed ROS, and which platform / cpu arch / OS this is? Binary distributions of ROS come with very specific dependencies on specific Boost versions, so not having the Boost version that ROS requires is strange and unexpected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Thank you for the comment. I installed the Kinetic version of ROS on Arch Linux. I was able to solve the problem by doing an upgrade of the ROS packages. I had installed the ROS when I had the BOOST version 1.63.0, but later had done a system upgrade. ROS was linked to previous version of BOOST.

---

Originally posted by [kennethjp](https://answers.ros.org/users/32048/kennethjp/) with karma: 16 on 2017-10-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-10-02**:
Could you please include such important information such as which OS you are running with your question next time? Installing on Arch immediately means 'from source' which needs a rather different when diagnosing your problems.

Without that info this would have been unsolvable.

**Comment by [kennethjp](https://answers.ros.org/users/32048/kennethjp/) on 2017-10-02**:
I am sorry that I missed out to include that information, I will include the information in the future questions.